# jQuery .val issue with empty array

Tags: jquery

I have a pretty basic setup in my application.

I generate a table that has an edit button.  When the edit button is clicked, a modal dialog pops up that I auto populate with a database response.

The function that I run when the button is clicked is contained in an external file;

```
function GetUserDetails(User_ID) {
    $.post("includes/admin/readUserDetails.php", {
        User_ID: User_ID
    },
    function (data, status) {
        var user = JSON.parse(data);
        $("#update_Actions").val(user.Actions); 
        $("#update_Actions_Selected").val(user.Actions_Selected);   
    });
    // Open modal popup
    $("#update_user_modal").modal("show");
}
```

The field being returned contains a comma separated list which is generated from a DB query.   The DB query json_encodes the response and forces it to be an object.

The reponse all looks good.  I see the data that I was expecting.

```
{"Actions":1, "Actions_Selected":"1,2,3"}
```

My modal is essentially empty except for two area to display the data being returned with HTML ID's that match the original JS snippet included above.

The issue here is that .val seems to get the Actions value correct and populates without a problem.  For Actions_Selected though, I get nothing.

The ultimate aim is to automatically mark a bootstrap multiselect with the values from the Actions_Selected string - This part I can do but I'm really struggling just to print the 1,2,3 to the console.  It's a string (varchar in the database too) and all other string entries I've tried work correctly.

If I change 1,2,3 in the database to a single entry, everything works fine.  It can be a number, letter or word

why does `.val` not just return me the string?  It appears to be that any string with commas is interpreted as an array but .val returns an empty array.

I'm sure this is something simple but I'm at a point where it's making no sense any more.

Comment: What is the type of the element with the id `update_Actions_Selected` ? I am pretty sure that if it is a Span for instance, it would be just printed "1,2,3". Maybe you have to process the 1,2,3 string to put the value on that element

Comment: please show the HTML of the modal. .val() only works on textboxes. If you have something else like a div then you need to use .text() or .html() to populate it.

Comment: BTW if your database is storing "1,2,3" as a string inside a single field then your database design is faulty. A relational database should never store multiple values in a single field - this is almost certainly a case where you ought to have a secondary table with a foreign key back to the main table, and store each of these values in a separate row.

Comment: The database only stores a single entry in each field.  The database query builds the format of the output by gathering the relevant data and sending it as a single string.

Comment: As for the layout of the HTML, that part is secondary - I can't even output the value to the console.  Once I can get it into the console, the rest should be easy.

Comment: You said "If I change 1,2,3 in the database to a single entry, everything works fine. It can be a number, letter or word" ...to me that implied that "1,2,3" was stored in one field, and if you changed that field to just "1" it would work. But maybe that's not what you meant, sorry

Comment: Anyway it's hard to see how you wouldn't even be able to log it to the console...here's a quick mockup: https://jsfiddle.net/nt9L6ezu/ (I had to use GET instead of POST due to the limitations of the mockup JSON site, but you see the idea. And it seems jQuery already saw the data as JSON and parsed it automatically to an object, so JSON.parse() was unnecessary. But apart from that you can see that it logs the values no problem. Perhaps this difference is in fact related to your issue: do you have any other console errors at all? You didn't really clarify what "struggling" actually means)